# Can members sign-up for two memberships from same organization?

Tags: civimember

Is it possible to use price sets to require members to sign up to 2 membership (ideally both autorenewed)? One is an annual insurance fee, the other a monthly membership fee. I'm getting error messages at the moment when testing that states that signing up to 2 memberships from one organization is not doable.

is making a 2nd, separate organisation for the insurance the way to go?

Thank you very much for your help,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, introducing a second "dummy" organisation is the way to go. This is described in more detail in the [user documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/defining-memberships/):

> Some organisations may want people to have two or more memberships of the same organisation that run concurrently. For example, an organisation focused on child health might want to offer a membership for parents that includes a parenting magazine and a membership for health professionals that includes a peer-reviewed journal and discounts at training events. Parents who are health professionals may want both memberships. A challenge to supporting this use case is that CiviCRM's Membership Up-Sell feature expects a contact to have only one active membership with a single organization at any given time. A 'workaround' for this is to create 'dummy' organisations for each of the possible concurrent memberships. For the situation just described, we would need to create an extra organisation for health professionals. Note that you don't have to expose the dummy organisation to your members on the website; it is for administrative purposes only.

Comment: Can i achieve the above with 2 autorenewing memberships of different renewal periods with price sets? I am trying but despite both memberships having 'required autorenewal' when i look at them in membership, when looking as a new user at the contribution page it looks like they would not auto renew. Or is it that the 'Membership will renew automatically.' sign doesn't get displayed in that scenario?
Thanks again for your help

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have experience with autorenewals yet. If in doubt, you could create a test setup with short renewal periods to test the behavior. Hopefully someone else can chime in and provide some better guidance.